# Bootstrap modal carousel height issue in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly I have thumbnail gallery structured like below.

```
    <div class = "row pictures">
        <div class="col-center col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
            <a href="#lightbox" data-toggle="modal" data-slide-to="1">
                 <img class="col-center img-responsive thumbnail" src="" >
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- some more pictures with different "data-slide-to" attributes --> 
   </div>
```

Code for modal, which is at the end of document, looks like that:

```
<div class="modal fade and carousel slide" id="lightbox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">         
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#lightbox" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#lightbox" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <!-- some more li elements with different "data-slide-to" attributes -->

                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <!-- some more items without active class -->
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#lightbox" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#lightbox" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem was, that modal was too big. 
I tried to fixed it with javascript below, but it only worked in Safari. I can't find a way to fix it in Firefox and Chrome.

I use jQuery 1.11.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.pictures a').on("click", function(){
        $('#lightbox').css({

            "margin-top": function () {
                return document.body.scrollTop;
            },
            "max-height": function () {
                return $(window).height();
            },
            "min-height": function () {
                return $(window).height();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noob question. I just had to set max-height of img elements to 100% and height to 100% for Firefox :P.